# AWK print specific fields without specific word

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, text-formatting

**Input:**

```
a-0;Password-1010;c-ss;d-fk;h-14;i-jawad;j-dd;Email-1@1.com;
a-7990:15:71;b-aa;c-1;Password-2020;h-iOS;Email-2@2.com;
```

**Output:**

```
1@1.com,1010
2@2.com,2020
```

my input file is the same as my example. i would like to only print the `Email` and `Password` directly with `,` separator.

each line in file contain stable words of `;Email-` and `;Password-`

I tried with `awk -F';' '{ print $8, $2 }'` but it's will not give my target because it's need some modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your desired outputs aren't consistently in the same field on each line, I'd suggest looping over fields, attempting to substitute the `Email-` and `Password-` prefixes, and recording the result if the substitution succeeds:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    FS=";"; OFS=",";
  }
  {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if (sub(/^Email-/,"",$i))
        e = $i; 
      else if (sub(/^Password-/,"",$i)) 
        p = $i;
     }
     print e, p
  }' file
1@1.com,1010
2@2.com,2020
```